# TypeError : mainArr.join is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, join

`mainArr.join()` is working only in the if part and not in the else part. it says

> TypeError : mainArr.join is not a function

but in that case it should not work in the if block also

```
 translatePigLatin("california");

 function translatePigLatin(str) {
     var mainArr = str.split("");

     if (mainArr[0] == "a" || mainArr[0] == "e" || mainArr[0] == "i" || mainArr[0] == "o" || mainArr[0] == "u") {
         str = mainArr.join("");
         str = str + "way";
     } else {
         var count = 0;
         var len = mainArr.length;

         for (i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++) {
             if (mainArr[i] != "a" && mainArr[i] != "e" && mainArr[i] != "i" && mainArr[i] != "o" && mainArr[i] != "u") {
                 mainArr = mainArr.push(mainArr[0]);
                 count++;
             } else {
                 i = mainArr.length;
             }
         }

         var mainStr = mainArr.join();
         mainStr = mainStr.substr(count - 1, len);
         mainStr = mainStr + "ay";
         str = mainStr;
     }

     return str;
 }
```

Comment: mainArr = mainArr.push(mainArr[0]);  <-- look at what push returns in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error is that you are assigning back to mainArr after the result of push which is wrong here `mainArr = mainArr.push(mainArr[0]);` as `mainArr.push(mainArr[0]);` returns the new length of the array

Apart from it you can improve your logic by using break instead of setting the iterator to array length in the else part

```js
console.log(translatePigLatin("california"));

 function translatePigLatin(str) {
     var mainArr = str.split("");

     if (mainArr[0] == "a" || mainArr[0] == "e" || mainArr[0] == "i" || mainArr[0] == "o" || mainArr[0] == "u") {
         str = mainArr.join("");
         str = str + "way";
     } else {
         var count = 0;
         var len = mainArr.length;

         for (i = 0; i < mainArr.length; i++) {
             if (mainArr[i] != "a" && mainArr[i] != "e" && mainArr[i] != "i" && mainArr[i] != "o" && mainArr[i] != "u") {
                 mainArr.push(mainArr[0]);
                 count++;
             } else {
                  break;
             }
         }
         var mainStr = mainArr.join("");
         mainStr = mainStr.substr(count - 1, len);
         mainStr = mainStr + "ay";
         str = mainStr;
     }

     return str;
 }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help, but i have a doubt, why is it wrong to assign the results of push to the mainArr?

Comment: because it retuns the length of the array after pushing an element, and hence your array will no longer remain an array. `concat()` returns a new array, it would be work with `mainArr = mainArr.concat(mainArr[0]);` however that is not required since mainArr.push() will do the job for you